# find first occurrence before a match using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to match the first occurrence of a pattern before a match was found.
To give it some context:

I have a csharp code file and I have a stored procedure name, I'm trying to figure out if | can match using capture groups the name of the method that is using this stored procedure.

e.g given the ofllowing code file

```
        public static public string GetUser(int user Id)
        {
            ....
            StoredProcedure sp = new StoredProcedure("Get_User");
            ....
        }

        public static int InsertUser(string sUitterTokenSecret, int nGroupID)
        {
            ....
            try
            {
                StoredProcedure sp = new StoredProcedure("SP_INSERT_USER");
                ....
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HandleException(ex);
            }

            return nInserted;
        }

        public static bool DeleteUser(int nSiteGuid, bool bLogOut = false)
        {
            ....
                StoredProcedure sp = new StoredProcedure("Delete_User");
            ...
        }
```

I am trying to find the name of the method that is calling  `SP_INSERT_USER`
so i used this 
`(public.*)(.|\n)*(SP_INSERT_USER)`

but the problem that its matching form the first occorence of `public static public string GetUser(int user Id)` up until `..StoredProcedure("SP_INSERT_USER");`

how can i get the first occurrence of `public...` before the stored procedure name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public.+?([A-Z].*)\((?:(?!public).|\n)*SP_INSERT_USER
```

Matches

```
public static int InsertUser(string sUitterTokenSecret, int nGroupID)
{
    ....
    try
    {
        StoredProcedure sp = new StoredProcedure("SP_INSERT_USER
```

And captures group #1

```
InsertUser
```

**Explanation**

- `public.+?` - matches occurance of `public` and everything after lazily
- `([A-Z].*)\(` - captures first occurance of a capital letter (method start) and everything that follows until the first occurance of opening parentheses `(`
- `(?:(?!public).|\n)*` - non-capturing group, matches any character or new line, except the word `public`
- `SP_INSERT_USER` - matches the word `SP_INSERT_USER`

Comment: thansk! .. but i culdnt make it work .. what am i missing ? https://regex101.com/r/row9W1/1/

Comment: Seems there is a ↵ (return/enter) in the end of regex after copying. Also if you use `/i` flag the captured method name is incorrect. If you need to use it, then replace the beginning with something like `public.*\s`

Comment: updated but note that the first capture group is the wrong method ..
it found GetUser instead of Insert user .. same as my regex :\ https://regex101.com/r/row9W1/2

Comment: Problem is with method visibility. In original question it was `public`, in the link it is `protected`. You can use alternation to match either of them `(?:protected|public).*\s(\w*)\((?:(?!public|protected).|\n)*SP_INSERT_USER`. If you need to support more visibility names add them with `|` also.